# Trying to throw an item to my crosshair direction via ray

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying with this more than 5 days now...
I am trying to make a simple mechanic in third person mode that is allowing me to throw my items at the center of my screen where my reticle (crosshair) is located... I am using cinemachine, and even tried to simplify that mechanic only when my second "aim" camera is activated...
But it still does not wanna throw the item exactly on the crosshair.. I tried making raycast hit function but it's not working. The item just flow in the direction that is not the crosshair aim at all... (Maybe it flows in direction of the camera, but not of crosshair direction)
Here is my code that i've written until now for raycasting and throwing function:

```
if (ObjectIwantToPickUp)


        {
            Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward * 100, Color.red);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Vector3 hitPos;
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit))
            {
                hitPos = hit.point;
            }
            else
            {
                hitPos = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 99;
            }


         forceDirection = hitPos - ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.position;
    }
```

And here is for throwing:

```
void throwObject()
        {
            if (hasItem == true && Input.GetKeyDown("t"))
            {
                BoxCollider[] bc = ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponents<BoxCollider>();
                foreach (BoxCollider b in bc)
                {
                    b.enabled = true;
                }
                ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
                ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false; // make the rigidbody work again
                //ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false; // make the rigidbody work again
                hasItem = false;
 
                ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.parent = null; // make the object no be a child of the hands
                ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(forceDirection.normalized * 15, ForceMode.Impulse);
                ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);
             
            }
```

Here is the full script in case I missed something: https://hatebin.com/uppepjkemf
Please, give me a hint, where am I wrong.
I am using cinemachine with two cameras and one Main camera with braincomponent in it.
Also, I am using a define position script, with simple two Vector3 positions in it.
I use that because I needed the picked up item to be parented exactly on pre-defined position in my hand

I have two cameras: Free Look camera and Virtual Camera (for aiming purposes) I change them via this script for changing the priority :

https://hatebin.com/chbofizvuk

Here is a short video what is not working:

https://vimeo.com/499738119

As u see, the "stick" in the scene does not match the crosshair when it's throwed.

Excuse me if I wasn't clear enough and for the messy code :D

Comment: By the way, you can use `AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.right * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);` Also you should avoid calling `GetComponent` so many times, especially in methods that get called very frequently. Keep the result in a field, use that feild, update it when necessary.

Comment: @Ruzihm Hey and thanks for the fast response! I tried adding this method and the result was that on pause I get much UnassignedReferenceException error but on start on picking up items i get this result: https://imgur.com/a/NIFzIW3
I tried with ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.right * 100, ForceMode.Impulse); instead of mine but nothing happens.

I made a simple script that defines my position in my hand, but I need that values to be for each individual gameobject so that I am calling the script this way :( I cannot think of better solution

Comment: As u see from the screenshot my ray does not point where my crosshair points :( 
Do u think that GetComponent method will affect my performance? Is there any clever way of doing that? 
Many thanks <3

Comment: Can u please tell me how to get the virtual camera's transform position ad forward direction? I am really confused with that cinemachine properties

Comment: Hey @Ruzihm Thank you very much for the suggestion!!!! I was able to make the ray from the aim camera (I think) but now my only problem is that when i throw the item it doesn't go upwards in the direction of the crosshair at all. Maybe it just go to the direction of the camera.
Here is the video: https://vimeo.com/499797894
And here is my code: https://hatebin.com/cippnsqyqh
Please tell me where is my mistake. Also, can I put both vectors in the start? Or they must be in update like now? Many thanks!!!

Comment: I found that when I am throwing it the item its throwed from lower point in my body (feels like legs), not the hand (where I hold the item) maybe that is the problem

Comment: Hey. I put that here 

ObjectIwantToPickUp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * 100 + Vector3.up * 5f, ForceMode.Impulse);

But literally no change :D Is this the right place to put it?

Comment: Hey man!!! That worked PRETTY WELL ACTUALLY! Oh my god thank you very much! I've been struggling now for 5 days for this..
One last question if u allow :)) Is this the right approach for making something like this? 
https://twitter.com/ABeginnersDevB1/status/1296215436783222784?s=20

I am trying to recreate the "throw" mechanics, and tomorrow I will try to handle the animations :) 

Many thanks once more! U saved me! :)

Comment: I touched on this below in the answer, but that case looks like the thrown object has gravity turned off on its rigidbody. That might be what you want, maybe not. If you turn off gravity, you can get rid of the `+ Vector3.up * 10f` bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Camera.main` is giving you the forward and position of the free look camera. You need to get the virtual camera's transform position and forward direction and use those instead.

First, add a field you can assign the aim camera in the inspector:

```
[SerializeField] Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCameraBase aimCam;
```

Then for the ray:

```
Vector3 aimOrigin = aimCam.State.FinalPosition; 
Vector3 aimDir = aimCam.State.FinalOrientation * Vector3.forward;
```

And then you probably want to add some vertical force so it travels a bit before hitting the ground:

```
AddForce(forceDirection.normalized * 30f + Vector3.up * 10f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

...or you could disable gravity on the object's Rigidbody. But then it may never hit the ground, so your mileage may vary with that.

Comment: Hey! :) I am wondering, if it is possible to take the ray from the reticle canvas that I am using for the "crosshair" in my cinemachine Aim camera, not from the camera itself? I think the throw will be even more accurate if I can throw the item directly where my crosshair is pointing?   
Is that possible?

Now, I have a simple script attached to my aim camera and make it activates after button is pressed. And the crosshair is turned on when the Aim camera activates.

Video of my current throwing function https://vimeo.com/503847266:
 
Logic for that - https://hatebin.com/hdcptllpng

Comment: @Moonrider Might be better to ask that in a separate question ;) then you can post more about the situation there. Consider mentioning back to this post and explaining why it's different